# How to uninstall ice cream sandwich update on huawei ascend g300?

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, external-sd

I have an ascend g300 from vodafone which I have unlocked and moved to another provider.

Yesterday I updated the os to ice cream sandwich following [these instructions](http://forum.vodafone.co.uk/t5/About-the-Community-and-Latest/Upgrade-to-Android-ICS-4-0-3-for-Huawei-Ascend-G300/td-p/1324672).

Since then the phone intermittently does not recognise the SD card when it wakes up from sleep. Sometimes it "prepares the SD card" and sometimes it says blank SD card or unrecognised format. Often if I restart the phone it starts working again.

The phone has also twice spontaneously restarted itself when it was supposed to be asleep.

I tried formatting the sd card in the phone and then reset to factory defaults. The phone was reset, but it didn't reformat the sd card, all my data was still there.

I'm now thinking I'd just like to uninstall the update, but how would I do that?

Comment: Might be worthwhile to read the thread at [modaco](http://www.modaco.com/topic/356806-guide-upgrade-and-downgrade-the-g300-between-gb-ics-and-jb-with-downloads/)

Answer (score 1):

There is an official Vodafone Gingrbread downgrade here.
http://www.huaweidevice.com/worldwide/downloadCenter.do?method=toDownloadFile&flay=software&softid=NDY4ODE=

Answer (score 0):

It would be quite difficult to do this.

Reason being:

1. It is *very* difficult to replace the new ICS bootloader
2. You would have to find the old original firmware
3. You would have to be rooted to be able to flash it

You would have to search forums such as [XDA-Developers](http://forum.xda-developers.com) for the stock firmware. You may be able to find rooting instructions there as well.